# Accessibility of abbr tag in some microformats

Tags: accessibility, microformats

Why do some micro-formats use the `abbr` tag? It may cause some accessibility issues.

```
The party is on <abbr class="dtstart" title="2005-10-10">the 10th</abbr>.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct, it's a significant accessibility issue; in 2008, [the BBC stopped using the hCalendar microformat](http://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/radiolabs/2008/06/removing_microformats_from_bbc.shtml) on their site for this reason.

As far as I can tell, the reason that the ABBR tag was used in this was was because the Microformat designers needed some *existing* HTML tag and attribute that they could re-purpose that would not have any other side-effects. (They couldn't invent a new HTML tag, since it would then fail to validate with existing pages; one goal with microformats is to be able to easily add them to existing pages.) ABBR+TITLE doesn't change the appearance or layout, so they likely *assumed* it was safe to use, and didn't realize at the time that TITLE can be read out by screenreaders, so needs to be human-readable, not a machine-readable string.

Or, put another way, they simply weren't aware that ATTR's TITLE can be used for accessibility.

There's [some background on why the abbr approach was chosen ad this page](http://tantek.com/log/2005/01.html#d26t0100).

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "predefined class" - you mean like class="isodate", or something like class="-2005-10-10" ?

Comment: *which* one? I gave you two options, saying "I mean that" doesn't tell me which :)

Comment: Oh, you are right. I mean `<span class="dtstart" title="2005-10-10">the 10th</span>` instead of `<abbr class="dtstart" title="2005-10-10">the 10th</abbr>`

Comment: That could still be a problem; title is still expected to be human-readable even on other tags. Some screenreaders might read out title instead of or in addition to the content. (Behavior of title in other tags is far less consistent than in abbr though, so it might seem to work in some cases and not in others!).

Comment: It turns out that perhaps the safest approach might have been something like `<span class="dtstart-2005-10-10">the 10th</span>` - while it looks ugly, adding an additional class (that's not referenced in the CSS) won't interfere with layout, visuals, or screenreader behavior... it could be fragile if there's script code on the page that reassigns class values; though most script libraries now safely add and remove additional class values leaving the original one intact.